# Load Excel file in MS Word Add-in with Office.js

Tags: office365, office-js, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an add-in for MS Word where I can choose an excel file from some kind of file picker and then use that data to generate multiple pages (invoices) in the word doc. The problem is, I can't seem to figure out what syntax I need to load an external Office file in the Add-in. Thanks for any pointers. I am on a mac with Office 2016 so VBA is pretty much out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the external Excel file using the Microsoft Graph web services.
You can find details about how to do this [here.](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately opengraph is not an option as the client doesn't want to have the excel files hosted on the cloud. Is there any way to access local files through the context api? The closest comparison I could draw would be node's FS module, for example.

Comment: @motleydev Not at this point in time, but we may bring support for this in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That helps me concentrate my efforts then. I'll accept the answer as it is correct due to my lack of original params.